# How to plot multiple bar plots with same x values, different y values, and final product is similar to that of using facet_wrap function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a dataset that has one column as x value for all other columns, and different y values, which are those other columns that looks like this (data frame is called freq_dist):

| Duration | D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 130 | 101 | 53 | 30 | 10 |
| 2 | 23 | 36 | 13 | 9 | 0 |

I want to set duration (column 1) as x value for all other columns, and display a bar chart using ggplot2 function. I tried to use geom_bar but instead of returning the values I already have in the table as my y values, it returns the counts of the occurance of each value, so instead of geom_bar, geom_col might be what I want, but how do I set my column 1 as the fixed x value for all other columns? I also tried to use simple barplot() function, which is essentially what I'm looking for, like this:

```
xx = freq_dist[,1]
yy = freq_dist[,2]

barplot(yy~xx)
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
freq_dist %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(Duration), value)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  labs(x = "Duration")
```

[image]

Comment: Updated to make it more like the base plot example with discrete x axis, and using the `D0` value as the breaks for the x axis. I think that's what you meant by "I want to set duration (column 1) as x value for all other columns" ?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the reply! Actually it's not using D0 value as the breaks for the x axis, but the duration as the x axis. So in the table, I treat D0 - D4 as events, for example, in D0 events, there are 130 of them that only lasted for 1 month, and 23 of them that lasted for 2 months. The figure format is what I'm looking for, it's just that instead of 4 figures of D1 to D4, it should be 5 figures of D0 to D4, with the duration as x axis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot into long format and use `geom_col`

```r
ggplot(pivot_longer(freq_dist, -1), aes(factor(Duration), value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = "Duration", fill = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.84, 0.25))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you very much! This is the expression of data that I'm looking for, but instead of putting them all on the same figure, I think I just need to add facet_wrap with the name of each event to separate them right?

Comment: @YinLongHuang oh I see - updated.